# Organizing multiple CoffeeScript files

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, frontend

I am working on an implementation of a web service where we are writing our front end code in CoffeeScript. The problem I have stumbled on is while the project is growing functionality has to be separated in different files. What I really need is a simple structure where in the `utils.coffee` file I will have the general functions which are required from every page and on each separate file I will have `page_foo.coffee` `page_bar.coffee` the specific functions. How can I structure it properly so I also make sure `utils.coffee` loads first and is accessible from everyone?

Comment: This isn't specific to CoffeeScript, but a general problem with JavaScript. That being said... see ["Structuring coffeescript code?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150455/structuring-coffeescript-code), and specifically my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150455/structuring-coffeescript-code/8303780#8303780).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check how it's done in [gae-init](http://bitbucket.org/lipis/gae-init) project (Disclaimer: I'm the creator).

The basic idea is that you have all the `*.coffee` files in one specific directory, and then a build script that compiles all the files and putting them in the correct paths.

Since you would like to be able to debug easily, while you're developing it, the build script should have an option to just compile them and another option to combine & minify them.

Comment: Thanks I changed my answer only because of the awesomeness of it. It provides not only a performance optimized structure for coffee but a great stack of tools I commonly use.

Comment: I didn't even know you could "unaccept" an answer :) You should look into CoffeeScript's own [cake](http://coffeescript.org/#cake) utility  if you go that route (one less language in the stack then)

Comment: This is a good idea, but it prevents you from having 2 files with the same name, like say views/navItem and models/navItem

Comment: @watson no it's not if you handle it correctly.. you should take into consideration the whole path and not only the filename..

Answer (score 7):

With CoffeeToaster you have the ability to include files that you'll need at the top of them, making sure your final ".js" file (that will be also a merge of all your CoffeeScript files) have everything in the proper order, for use inside the browser.

Take a look on the docs:
http://github.com/serpentem/coffee-toaster

It comes also with a packaging system that when enabled will use your folder's hierarchy as namespaces declarations to your classes if you want so, then you can extends classes from multiple files, do imports and son, such as like:

```
#<< another/package/myclass
class SomeClass extends another.package.MyClass
```

The build configuration is extremely minimalist:

```
# => SRC FOLDER
toast 'src_folder'
    # => VENDORS (optional)
    # vendors: ['vendors/x.js', 'vendors/y.js', ... ]

    # => OPTIONS (optional, default values listed)
    # bare: false
    # packaging: true
    # expose: ''
    # minify: false

    # => HTTPFOLDER (optional), RELEASE / DEBUG (required)
    httpfolder: 'js'
    release: 'www/js/app.js'
    debug: 'www/js/app-debug.js'
```

There's even a debug option that compile files individually for ease the debugging processes and another useful features.

Comment: How can I expose a complex namespace e.g. acme.sales.admin so that this is the root for my app?

Comment: You create these folders one inside each other and put your files inside "acme/sales/admin/yourfile.coffee".

Comment: CoffeeToaster has been [discontinued](https://github.com/arboleya/coffee-toaster/wiki) and forked to a new project, [Polvo](https://github.com/polvo/polvo).

Answer (score 5):

Execution order is respected on browsers, so just include `utils.js` first.

A tool like CodeKit(http://incident57.com/codekit/) can compile and minify+join all your `.coffee` files into one `.js`, that's easy to do with a shell script too.

If your app is really large, read up on [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) and [Asynchoronous Module Loading](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD). It will allow you to manage dependencies very easily and only load what's necessary:

```
# page_foo.coffee
define ['lib/utils'], ($) ->
    // code that uses 'utils'
```

Answer (score 2):

What I do is to write a Cake task to join and compile files in a predetermined sequence, for example

```
task 'build', 'join and compile *.coffee files', ->
  exec "coffee -j #{outJS}.js -c #{strFiles}", exerr
```

where `outJS` is the filename where I want the compiled JavaScript and `strFiles` is a string of filenames

Additionally you can add tasks to minify the compiled code using YUICompressor or your favorite tool. And during development watching, joining, compiling can also be automated

```
task 'watch', 'watch and compile changes in source dir', ->
  watch = exec "coffee -j #{outJS}.js -cw #{strFiles}"
  watch.stdout.on 'data', (data)-> process.stdout.write data
```

Have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1537200)