# Rails 3.2 + CoffeeScript + Namespacing + Separate Files = Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have one companion script file for a Rails model, that uses code I've broken down into a hierarchy of over a dozen classes, for things like jQuery/Bootstrap UI code, factoring out similarities between different types of dialog, and so on. Let's say I'm working with `articles.js.coffee` as the "main page script" here.

I can define Coffeescript classes, namespace them as something like `window.ourproject.OurUIDialog`, and save them in separate, per-class source files such as `app/assets/javascripts/OurUIDialog.js.coffee`. Restart the Rails server, and that class can be subclassed, e.g., `window.ourproject.PostInfoDialog extends window.ourproject.OurUIDialog`. As long as `PostInfoDialog` is in `articles.js.coffee` (where the instantiation of the `PostInfoDialog` is), all is well.

But, if I move the subclass (`PostInfoDialog`) out into a separate file, e.g., `PostInfoDialog.js.coffee`, then attempting to do anything at all with it within the main articles script produces

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`

Again:

1. This revolves around a Rails model's companion script file, here called `articles.js.coffee`;
2. `window.ourproject.OurUIDialog` gets picked up whether it's in its own file or in `articles.js.coffee`
3. `window.ourproject.PostInfoDialog` (which extends `OurUIDialog`) can only be used if it's *not* in a separate file, *even though* viewing the generated HTML shows `PostInfoDialog` being included with all the other script files.

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure this out, and I didn't have much left to begin with. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Structuring coffeescript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150455/structuring-coffeescript-code)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that Trevor Burnham answered my question when he answered [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150455/structuring-coffeescript-code); I just didn't see it the first dozen times I searched. :-P

Thanks to both of you for reading this one, though. :-)