# Rails nested_form file error in assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, assets, precompile

Rails tells me, that I've got some errors in application.js

```
$ rake assets:precompile
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/local/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Unexpected token: operator (*=) (line: 12013, col: 1, pos: 341357)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:1720:22)
    at js_error (<eval>:1728:15)
    at croak (<eval>:2189:17)
    at token_error (<eval>:2196:17)
    at unexpected (<eval>:2202:17)
    at <eval>:2580:17
    at maybe_unary (<eval>:2665:27)
    at expr_ops (<eval>:2692:32)
    at maybe_conditional (<eval>:2696:28)
    at maybe_assign (<eval>:2720:28)
  (in /home/medy75/Dropbox/Ruby/projectManager_login/ProjectManager/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/local/bin/rake asset...]
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My aplication.js looks like this:

```
#aplication.js
//= require jquery
//
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//
//= require_tree .
//
*= require prototype_nested_form
//
//= require jquery_nested_form
//
//= require bootstrap
```

And when I removed this line, it told that it couldn't find nested form file.

EDIT:

When I make //= require jquery_nested_form it makes this:

```
$ rake assets:precompile
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/local/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production            RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
couldn't find file 'prototype_nested_form'
  (in             /home/medy75/Dropbox/Ruby/projectManager_login/ProjectManager/app/assets/javascripts/applica    tion.js:21)
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/local/bin/rake asset...]
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: is your syntax right? why are you using "*"?

Comment: I mafe by some tuto. I've got no idea, how this works. But when I delete "*", there is a same problem only with : Unexpected token: operator (=)...

Comment: just try it again with `//= require prototype_nested_form`

Comment: A edited question. Couldn't find nested form file...

Comment: read the link I posted below - I guess you also need to include it

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure your syntax here is wrong. Have a look at this post: [Rails 3.1 asset pipeline and manually ordered Javascript requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149961/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-and-manually-ordered-javascript-requires)