# How do I load AngularJS bootstrap module correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

In my Rails app, I have `ui-bootstrap-0.2.0.js` in the `vendor/assets/javascripts` directory. I have required the file in my `application.js` file.

I get an error when I specify the bootstrap as my dependency in this line, `angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']);`, as instructed to do here, http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Chrome detects a `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined` at this defined module:
`angular.module("ui.bootstrap", ["ui.bootstrap.accordion", ...])` in the `ui-bootstrap-0.2.0.js`.

However, `angular.js` catches an error `No module:ui.bootstrap`. So it seems both of these javascript files cannot see eachother. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Did you include `angular.js` *before* bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I made sure angular.js was loaded before the bootstrap.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Rails' asset pipeline. Are the files requested asynchronously or does Rails generate the resulting `script` tags? That is, is there final output to look at to see what's going on?

Comment: Rails generates the resulting script tags in development.

Comment: Then Rails is ordering them incorrectly. Check out jpmorin's comment to his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it in my project:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script>
```

And this is how I set my application module:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap','ngResource']);
```

Comment: I'm probably going to do it like yours manually, but I would prefer that I could require it in my Rails application.js using ```// require bootstrap_file```, then load all my js files by loading the application.js

Comment: Could this post help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149961/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-and-manually-ordered-javascript-requires