# Fullcalendar 2 not rendering, Bootstrap 3 & Rails 4 Incompatibility? (Jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I've been trying to render a calendar in my rails 4 app and the calendar doesn't show up when I'm using Bootstrap 3.

I rebuilt the app with JUST the fullcalendar 2 and bootstrap 3 files and it still doesn't render.

These are 2 jsfiddles in the comments (each with a separate js call for the calendar).  They both use the files I'm trying to require for my app.  I've been working for several days on this and I can't understand what's going on.  I haven't changed any files or done anything.

As you can see, I'm using clean, cdn assets.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please see jsfiddles in the comment section.

Comment: examples:  http://jsfiddle.net/somedancetoforget/hX2HD/5/

    http://jsfiddle.net/somedancetoforget/Hg4Y9/1/

Comment: I found the issue with your fiddle to be the order of your external resources. Put the fullcalendar dependencies first in your fiddles. jsfiddle.net/marcrazyness/9zpe2

Comment: Thank you!!!  Does this mean I need a specific order for these files when I call the js in asset pipeline or if I'm linking the script files old-school style?  I'm new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with your fiddle to be the order of your external resources. Put the fullcalendar dependencies first in your fiddles. jsfiddle.net/marcrazyness/9zpe2/.

**Edit:**
Checkout this article: [Rails 3.1 asset pipeline and manually ordered Javascript requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149961/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-and-manually-ordered-javascript-requires)