# Is Fullcalendar 2 incompatible with Bootstrap 3 and Rails 4 (I really need help...days on this)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

My fullcalendar calendar is not rendering at all. Ever.

Earlier today I posted my Jsfiddle testing all my files for compatibility before putting them in my rails 4 app.  That question was answered and my jsfiddle showed my bootstrap 3 and  fullcalendar 2 working together fine.

This is that posting: [Fullcalendar 2 not rendering, Bootstrap 3 & Rails 4 Incompatibility? (Jsfiddle included)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744762/fullcalendar-2-not-rendering-bootstrap-3-rails-4-incompatibility-jsfiddle-i)

Then I put them in my rails 4 app.

I put them in asset pipeline, in correct order and NOTHING showed up.
Then I turned off asset pipeline and old-school linked them in the head of my application.html.  Nothing showed up (except my navbar and footer).

I removed my navbar and footer and tried again. NOTHING.

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  I haven't modified the code.  I'm just using these few files posted on the jsfiddle (that I'll put a link to in the comments).

Can someone point me in a direction to test/ look.

Thank you!

Comment: These are the files I'm using actually working together...unlike in my app: http://jsfiddle.net/somedancetoforget/96Z3t/6/

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: If by that you mean the 'application error' with the red bars in the browser...no, it renders the navbar & footer (when I call them).  If you don't mean that...I'm sorry, I'm very new and I don't know what you're talking about (thought I do know what rails c is...I just don't know how to check for errors).  Though when my application is loading, I looked at the terminal read out (sorry for my terminology) and found this error: [2014-07-14 19:59:28] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer ..I tried look around for what a 'console error' was, so that I didn't give you a useless answer

Comment: @somedancetoforget : `right click > inspect element > Console` try reload your page and look at the console.

Comment: Take a look at full calender-rails gem https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails

Comment: It will integreate fullcalender with your rails asset pipeline.

Comment: @deep I tried it, but got hung up on the precompile text I was supposed to put in the application.erb.  Is that what I need? Precompiling?

Comment: @anonymousxxx Thanks!  I did that and I found this error in the fullcalendar file...thought  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL regarding the line 8 of the fullcalendar.js ....which is just the start of the js...I don't understand

Comment: I think that error because you have copy pasted code from jsfiddle to your editor (some problem on stackoverflow because it), try to write your script (js). Or can you post your script of js file on your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to integrate full calendar in a rails app

1. First Download [moment.min.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js) and [fullcalendar.min.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.0.2/fullcalendar.min.js) file and place them inside `vendor/assets/javascripts` directory.
2. Download [fullcalendar.css](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.0.2/fullcalendar.css) and [fullcalendar.print.css](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.0.2/fullcalendar.print.css) file and place them inside `vendor/assets/stylesheets` directory.
3. Now in your `application.js` file add the javascript files right after jquery like

   ```
   #application.js
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require moment.min
   //= require fullcalendar.min
   //= require turbolinks
   //= require_tree .
   ```
4. In your `application.css` file add reference to the css files like

   ```
   *= require_tree .
   *= require fullcalendar
   *= require fullcalendar.print
   *= require_self
   ```
5. In your view add a div with an id `calender`

   ```
   <div id='calendar'></div>
   ```
6. Now create a js file `calendar.js` inside `app/assets/javascript` with the following code

   ```
   $(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     // put your options and callbacks here
     })
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you.  This is very helpful.  Unfortunately I'm stuck with an "undefined variable" in (several) less files error.  I've rebuilt my app again to see if it was on me.  I'm stuck on this error...stuck because I have no idea why it didn't show up before.  Ugh. I'll respond to your answer when I get over this nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt this app three times and verified the css and less before finally figuring out what I had done wrong.

I am very new to rails, and though that I HAD to include require_tree in the manifest.  Once I removed it and just manually added the necessary files, my app worked beautifully.  And I felt like a dunce.  I hope this helps someone else.