# Load JS files in specific order

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have to load JS files in order in a rails view.
In the rails view I have:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "diagrams" %>
```

The diagrams.js manifest file have the required JS files in the order that is needed:

```
//= require diagramtool/kinetic
//= require diagramtool/diagramtool0
//= require diagramtool/diagramtool1
//= require diagramtool/diagramtool2
```

But they are not load in the order specified in the diagrams.js file.

[image]

I already have removed the `require_tree .` in the application.js file.

What do I have to do to load the JS files in a specific order?

**Edit1:**
Every time I click in the view I get different results (it seems random):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't really understand what is going on here!! Is that difficult in Rails to load JS files in order? I have read some things about the asset pipeline and I don't understand this random behaviour. If I refresh the page always works, the files are always loaded in order. Any help?

**Edit2:**
The view source is like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting //require_self after you list the other scripts? This SO article may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149961/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-and-manually-ordered-javascript-requires

Comment: Thanks @BrMcMullin! Yes I have tried with //require_self and I get the same result. Any other ideia why is this happening?

Comment: But the view source pic you show here has your js files in the correct order. They should always load in the same order. Maybe you're having a problem with Turbolinks. Try removing that from your application.js file.

Comment: Thanks @diego.greyrobot! It works properly with the Turbolinks turned off. Do you have any idea why is this happen when the Turbolinks are on?